# How do you bind multiple onclick functions to a specific node?

Tags: javascript, binding, onclick

When an HTML node is clicked on, on my page, I would like something to happen to it.

I would also like something else to happen to it.

Then I decide, I want something further to happen to it. In other words, I would like to continue binding it to new actions. But rather than hardcoding this into the original `onclick` function, I want to create a function to do this.

In other words, I want something like this:

```
function addClickBinding(node, functionToPerform){
     node.onclick = function(e){
           //some stuff
           functionToPerform(stuff in here)
     }
```

The problem with this as I've discovered is that if I call it with the same node, the previous `onclick` gets over ridden.

How do I continue to add new `onclick` attributes to the same node?

**NOTE:** I do not want to use JQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the`element.addEventListener('click', function(e) { }, false);`. Read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener). Otherwise you could wrap the functions that you'd like to be called with a function, and make that equal to the`.onclick`.

Answer (score -1):

If you are simply trying to make it so multiple functions get run at once, then you could just have a function to do that:

```
function clickControl()
{
    doThis();
    doThat();
    etc();
}
```

Assuming that this isn't the question, and you want certain things to happen under certain conditions, then you just need to put those in there as well:

```
function clickControl()
{
    if(something)
    {
         doThis();
    }else if(something_else)
    {
        doThat();
    }else
    {
        etc();
    }
}
```

finally, if you want something different to happen to it every time, set a global variable:

```
var clickStep = 1;

function clickControl()
{
    switch(clickStep++)
    {
        case 1:
            doThis();
            break;
        case 2:
            doThat();
            break;
        case 3:
            etc();
            break;
    }
}
```

I hope I answered your question here. I haven't slept all night, so if I'm off about this thing then I apologise.